# We have implemented a real-time dashboard in SharePoint Online - Is it possible to hide a web part until it is fully rendered by the browser?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, sharepoint-online

We have implemented a real-time dashboard in SharePoint Online. While the web part is updating [the screen refreshes every 5 minutes] we can see the underlying html (1st Screenshot) before it is fully rendered into a graphically representation (2nd Screenshot).

[image: Screenshot]

[image: Screenshot]

Questions: Is it possible to hide the web part until it is fully rendered by the browser so that we don’t see the source html, but only the final result (i.e. the graphics)? Can this be done via CSS/JavaScript embedded in the page as we have limited experience with SharePoint Designer?

Thanks in advance for your help,

Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to add a content editor web part to the page and include a div that is hidden via CSS by default.  You could then insert your list view web part into that div so that it would be hidden at page load.  At the end of your JavaScript that loads the images, you could simply change the style of the containing DIV so that it is now visible.

On a different note, have you considered simply using a Content Query Web Part with custom XSL that pulls the data from the list and renders it as desired on the page?  That would avoid the issue entirely,

Comment: I followed your suggestion and it works 95% of the time [network/backend issues sometimes impacts pagination]. Strange that SharePoint keeps changing the display: none attribute to display: block every-time I edit the page – so I’m forced to reedit it again. Thanks for your suggestion – I can work with this. Alex

Answer (score 0):

Could you go into the web part options and set the AJAX option to Enable Asynchronous Load and see if that helps?

Comment: Hi PirateEric,
AJAX sadly doesn't help as the conversion of the html into the graphics is undertaken by a JavaScript routine embedded in an content editor web part [which doesn't support AJAX] at the bottom of the page. The entire page needs to be refreshed for the graphics to show. Turning on AJAX will result in the web part refreshing, displaying html, but not displaying the graphics. Thanks, Alex

Comment: You could maybe convert it to a data view web part and it should all just work normally and not need a text to html javascript function to convert it for you.

Comment: As mentioned previously we have limited experience with SharePoint Designer [our version is now 2013], even though the frontend is 2010. Therefore, if creating a data view web part requires SharePoint Designer then we cannot proceed. Our super users are most annoyed by MS’ decision to remove the GUI interface from the development tool, which is restricting my room to manoeuvre. Thanks again for your suggestions. Alex